#  JSON says it's null?

Tags: jquery, json

My server side code:
returns an array:

```
return array('success'=>true, 'client_id' => $_GET['id']);
```

which is then echo'd

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

JSON looks like this when outputting;

```
{"success":true,"client_id":"db7A8"}
```

But when I run

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            var newBucket = $.parseJSON(responseJSON);
            alert(newBucket.client_id);
            }
```

it says that it's null (it's a function of [AJAX upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)), any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: What does Firebug (or similar) show as the *actual* response? (This is the only thing that matters!)

Comment: echo `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);`
 should be `echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: what is the value of responseJSON in the onComplete function?

Comment: pst, response where? in the header? echo'd? it's what I posted. genesis, no go. BNL how can I output it when it's an object?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified proper ContentType header while returning JSON data from php? IE and Chrome doesn't like to receive JSON under the wrong ContentType header.

If that doesn't solve your problem try using this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

```
var encoded = $.toJSON(responseJSON);
var newBucket = $.evalJSON(encoded);
alert(newBucket.client_id);
```

Edit : the code above is using the mentioned jquery plugin to serialize the responseJSON before parsing it. You may use other alternative methods to do the same if you don't want to use that jquery plugin.

Comment: tried specifying header('Content-type: application/json'); no go, I prefer not using any more libraries or plugins if I don't need.